# How to execute perl script from a Windows Powershell script

Tags: perl, powershell

I have the below `PowerShell` code:

```
$HOME_DIR=[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")
$WORKING_PATH="C:\tests\automation"
$TOOLS_PATH="$WORKING_PATH\Tools"

Start-Process -FilePath "$HOME_DIR\perl\perl.bat" "$TOOLS_PATH\my_perl_script.pl" -ArgumentList 'arg1' 'arg2' -NoNewWindow
```

I'm getting error:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\tests\automation\Tools\my_perl_script.pl'.
At C:\RunUIAutomaionTests.ps1:46 char:14
+ Start-Process <<<<  -FilePath "$HOME_DIR\perl\perl.bat" "$TOOLS_PATH\my_perl_script.pl"
-ArgumentList 'arg1' 'arg2' -NoNewWindow
&emsp;&emsp;+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
&emsp;&emsp;+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :<br>&emsp;&emsp;PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

What I'm missing?How should I execute `my_perl_script.pl` using `perl.bat` with the arguments `'arg1'` and `'arg2'`?

Comment: File path can't consist of two paths :-) Move your pl path into arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so complicated?
You can call perl doirectly like that:
...

> $TOOLS_PATH="$WORKING_PATH\Tools"
>   ...

perl $TOOLS_PATH\my_perl_script.pl arg1 arg2

Just make sure perl executable is in Windows path